# How to create listbox from list

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, mvvm, listbox

How can I add items to listbox when item source is a list.

XAML:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource viewModel}, Path=CultureEvents}">
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource viewModel}, Path=ItemTitle}" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="116,364,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="334" Foreground="White" />
</DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

In viewmodel I have list:

```
public List<CultureEvent> CultureEvents { get; set; }
```

And property:

```
public string ItemTitle
    {
        get
        {
            return ?;
        }
        set
        {
            ? = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ItemTitle"));
        }
    }
```

But I don't know what to put into property.

Answer (score 0):

```
private string _itemTitle
public string ItemTitle
    {
        get
        {
            return _itemTitle;
        }
        set
        {
            _itemTitle = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ItemTitle"));
        }
```

You would generate The list something like this,

```
 CultureEvents = new List<CultureEvent>();
 CultureEvents.Add(new CultureEvent{Title = "Yourvalue"} );
```